# How does Scala treat a list as a function?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a list of int. I can invoke a `lift` function on it and get another function with type `T => Option[T]`.

```
val f0: Int => Option[Int] = List(1, 2).lift

println(f0.apply(0)) // Some(1)
println(f0.apply(1)) // Some(2)
println(f0.apply(2)) // None
```

But how does it work? Why do I can apply a `lift` (from `PartialFunction` trait) function to `List`? Is there some implicit magic?

Comment: Read this : http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-seq-map-and-set-as-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned `List[T]` is a subtype of `PartialFunction[Int, T]`. Now `List` is not a direct subclass of `PartialFunction`.
It's the `Seq` trait that extends `PartialFunction` in the form `trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int, A]` .

Seq is the trait inherited by collections like `List` which in turn gives them the methods like `Lift` etc.
I think its a matter of perspective.

I would look at that as `Seq`is a `PartialFunction` that goes  from Int values to the element type of the sequence and whose `isDefinedAt` method returns `true` for the interval from `0` until `length`.

Look [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.Seq).

Likewise for maps all maps extend the trait `MapLike` which extends `PartialFunction`. Now a `Map[A,B]` extends `PartialFunction[A,B]`.
So think of Maps as PartialFunctions where the `isDefinedAt` method returns `true` for all defined `keys`.

I am copying a sample from my worksheet . I assign `Map` to a `PartialFunction`
to illustrate the sameness.

```
val m = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4)
                                                  //> m  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3
                                                  //| , d -> 4)
  val f2: PartialFunction[String, Int] = m        //> f2  : PartialFunction[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)


  m.isDefinedAt("d")                              //> res5: Boolean = true
  f2.isDefinedAt("e")                             //> res6: Boolean = false
```

Look [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.MapLike).

Comment: I think this behavior related to all Collections API. For instance, we also could treat a map as a function: `Map(1 -> 1).isDefinedAt(1)`. However Map isn't an indexed Seq.

Comment: Yes true. I was talking about the `List` .

Comment: i have added explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "implicit magic". `List[T]` simply is a subclass of  `PartialFunction[Int, T]`